# Building "is diagonalizable " with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm practicing about NumPy library( beginner), and I want to create a function that decide if a given square matrix is diagonalizable. 
It seems that the next function returns true for every matrix, and i'm wondering why is that happening:

```
def diagon_form_of_matrix(matrix)

    #diagon iff #eigenvectors=rank of matrix
    eigvalues,eigvectors=LA.eig(matrix)
    num_rows,num_columns=eigvectors.shape
    matrix_dim=matrix.shape[0]# it's squared
    return(num_columns==matrix_dim)\]
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if all the eigenvalues are all different, since there are repeats if the matrix isn't diagonalizable.

Comment: It's fine that there will be eigenval with multiplicity.. The matrix should be diagonlizable 
 as long it has "enough" eigen vectors. It seems that when I run the function LA.eig(matrix) , it's always find enough different eigenvectors(including the case where there aren't such vectors)

Comment: You might be getting rounding errors - perhaps we need an input you get the wring answer for to help better

Comment: I think so also.. For instance the matrix [[2,1],[0,2]]